# C# - XMLDocument Save() not working properly every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file, azure

I am having a strange issue in writing and accessing an XML file using c#.
I am simply adding elements and sub elements on my XML file. Its working properly on local server. I never found any issue in local server, but when I am uploading that code to AZURE Server then below things happened.

1. Sometimes work Perfectly.
2. Sometimes save new data and remove after sometime.
3. Sometimes it doesn't save anything.

I couldn't found any issue on this operation. Below is my code.

```
    protected readonly string Path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/DataFiles/XYZ.xml");
    protected readonly XDocument ParmarTailorXml = XDocument.Load(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/DataFiles/XYZ.xml"));

    /// <summary>
    /// Add new element in xml 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="descendent"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected bool AddNewElement(string descendent, XElement value)
    {
        try
        {
            var mainElement = ParmarTailorXml.Element("abc");
            if (mainElement != null)
            {
                var subElement = mainElement.Element(descendent);
                if (subElement != null)
                    subElement.Add(value);
                ParmarTailorXml.Save(Path);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected bool AddSubNewElement(string id, string attr, string parent, string child, string descendent, XElement value)
    {
        try
        {
            var mainElement = ParmarTailorXml.Element("abc");
            if (mainElement != null)
            {
                var subElement = (from temp in mainElement.Element(parent).Elements(child) where temp.Attribute(attr).Value == id select temp);
                if (subElement != null)
                    subElement.Elements(descendent).LastOrDefault().Add(value);
                ParmarTailorXml.Save(Path);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to find out what's actual issue!

Comment: Coding like `catch (Exception) { return false; }` is a terrible anti-pattern and simply hides bugs. You should never catch just `Exception`. You should read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/.

Comment: Code doesn't work intermittently.  If you are getting intermittent results than there is an issue with the data input(s).  You probably don't have the complete xml file.  Where are you waiting in the code to read entire xml file?